# Hide content for the Iframed page through Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i have this code with and I want to hide the logo and other content of Iframed page. Already used Div and it is works, but it is temporary solution. I want to hide it through CSS make it permanently

```html
<div style="left: 0px; position: relative; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 450px;">
    <iframe style="position: relative; top: -73px;" src="https://awewallet.com/cardsystem/chkbal" width="550" height="615" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
         </div>
```

Comment: You can't modify anything inside the iframe when it is not from same domain as page it is injected in. If current solution is working ... use it

Comment: @charlietfl i agree I can't hide but do you have any Other way to hide the content...

Comment: Only by adding overlays that cover part of the iframe or setting negative margin or position on iframe so it moves up inside it's parent

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I already did the same but it is the best way to do the same..

Comment: Yes...no simple way to do it unless you control the code inside the iframe also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)